# How can I get a powershell script to exit with a non-zero code when an az cli command fails?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I use the az cli in a powershell script on my CI/CD environment (bamboo if it matters). When an az cli command returns an error the script keeps executing like nothing happened which is problematic.

I assume I need to wrap some stuff in a `try/catch`? Is there a flag for the az cli that can throw?

Comment: you'd need to check lastexitcode after every command of az cli

Comment: @4c74356b41 where is that found? How do I check for that? Will I use the az cli `--query/--output` flags perhaps?

Comment: check the linked answer something like: `az do something here; if ($lastexitcode -ne 0) { exit $lastexitcode }`. it doesnt have to be an `.exe`. any external binary will have the same behaviour

Comment: @4c74356b41 So I need to run my az cli command and then call Get-Process and try to find it? That wont work for me. For one, the command can be really fast. For two, other az cli commands can be executed at the exact same time on the build agent. EDIT: It might work actually. Ill try it.

Comment: no, you dont need `get-process`, check my previous comment and the answers on that linked thread

Comment: @4c74356b41 Looks like it worked. I did: `& az account set -s 'fake-subscription-for-testing'; $LASTEXITCODE` and I got a 1 back. When I use a real subscription that passes the test, I get a 0 back. Guess i have to wrap all my calls in a shit ton of conditionals.

Comment: not much you can do besides that, i'm afraid

Comment: Looks like for the az cli in my case, the & is not necessary. Thats just to force PS to acknowledge the line as a command correct? It has no effect on the auto variable? Also, what happens when two commands execute at the same time? Could that race condition change $LASTEXITCODE?

Comment: you cannot really execute 2 commands at the same time in the same console. `&` - not needed, you are correct

Answer (score 1):

To exit on exception with a specific exit code, just specify it after exit:

```
try{
   #Code Here....
}
catch{
   Exit 25   
}
```

Comment: this wont work with az cli

Comment: That was my next question. How would PS know that the CLI errored? The CLI is written in Python and from what I understand is not "throwing" errors in a PS way.